# Rails 3 - make API call when user logs-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth

I have a Tumblr app running on Rails 3.0.10, where users are logged in using oauth, in the manner described [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth).

I want to run a method that updates the user's details thru an API call, whenever he logs in. What is the best way to do so? Is it ok if I simply call the method from within the create method of the SessionController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Neil suggested before me, you should consider creating a delayed job for the API call so users won't have to wait for the API to respond to your call.

I would push the API call into something like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/). It's a nifty little message queue deamon. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with Delayed Job, as it seems to be better documented, both on Heroku and Github.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this is exactly the way to do it, but possibly also add into the mix doing it as a delayed job if you can so the user isn't sat there waiting.